# Getting frequent error while passing data from form to a URL in NodeJS the error is cannot post /urlname

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, backend, web-development-server

this is my from page where I post  to a URL articles but it gives me error that cannot POST/URL name
every time I want to save a new article it gives me same error cannot post/URL name

```
 <form action="/routes/articles" method="post">
                   //here I simply used a partials!
                            {{>form}}
                    
                        </form>
        this is code where I get data through post method that is mentioned and then it is saved to the database const express = require('express');
                    const router = express.Router();
                    const Article = require("../model/schema")
                    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
                      res.send('hey !!');
                    });
                    
                    router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
                      res.render('articleGenerator');
                    }); 
                    router.get("/:id",(req,res)=>{
                    })
                  
                    router.post("/",async(req,res)=>{
                    
                    const newArticle = new Article({
                    
                    title:req.body.title,
                    description:req.body.description,
                    markdown:req.body.markdown
                    })
                    //this code saves new article that is send from form page mentioned above
                    try {
                      newArticle = await newArticle.save();
                      res.redirect(`/articles/${newArticle.id}`)
                    } catch (error) {
                      
                      res.render("/articleGenerator",{articles:newArticle});
                    
                    }
                    })
```

this is my main file  that i run Note that I have exported one route articlesjs that saves data.
module.exports = router;

```
                        const express = require('express');
                    const app = express();
                 
                    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
       this is for data base mongoose//
                    mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blogging-site",{
                      useNewUrlParser:true,
                      useUnifiedTopology:true,
                      useCreateIndex:true
                    })
                    //here i get the routes of page that is saving the data
                    const theRoutes = require('./routes/articles')
                    app.use('/theroutes', theRoutes);
                    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
                    
                    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                      res.render('index');
                    });
                
                    app.listen(3000, () => {
                      console.log('server is up and running!!');
                    });
```

Comment: try to update the route in your form 
 <form action="/theroutes" method="post">

Comment: @Max thanks man !! the solution  you provided worked.